# While retornando dados duplicados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Bom dia Galera, eu tenho esta query

```
$query = "SELECT p.*, c.nomeCategoria AS categoria FROM produto AS p INNER JOIN produto_categoria AS c"; 
$dados = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

e um while que retorna o valor dentro de um select.

```
  <select name="categoriaProduto">
  <?php
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dados))
   {
    ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["categoria"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["categoria"]; ?></option>
  <?php
 }
  ?>
</select>
```

só que na minha página ele ta mostrando os dados do select duplicados, eu tenho 3 itens cadastrados na tabela categoria_produto.

Queria saber se tem algo que fiz de errado no código.
Obrigado!!
[image: Mostra de como os dados estao.]

Comment: Esse combo é apenas para exibir as categorias? se for não precisa de inner join basta um select simples.

Comment: Ficaria entao `select nomeCategoria FROM categoria_produto` ?

é que na verdade, esse é o cadastro de produtos, e o combo realmente é só para mostrar as categorias cadastradas, mas a que for escolhida no combo, terá o codigo gravado na tabela de produtos.

Comment: vc não tem uma tabela só para categorias?

Comment: Você tem que ter duas queries. Uma para os dados do produto e outra para as categorias. Se você fizer um join você precisa especificar as colunas de ligação com o `ON`. Veja na documentação como realizar um inner join.

Comment: @rray sim eu tenho. tabela produtos, onde tem uma coluna "categoriaProduto" de tipo int, e a tabela categoria_produtos onde tem as colunas "idCategoria" e "nomeCategoria".

Comment: Um produto tem só um categoria?

Comment: @rray sim, é bem simples

Comment: Entendi, então faz um `select idCategoria, nomeCategoria FROM categoria_produto` o `idCategoria` vai no value do combo e `nomeCategoria` vai dentro do option.

Comment: @rray valeu cara!!! deu certinho para o que eu precisava!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT p.*, c.nomeCategoria AS categoria FROM produto AS p
INNER JOIN produto_categoria AS c
```

A atual consulta traz os **produtos** com categorias associadas, imagino que exista mais de um produto com a mesma categoria na tabela por aparece categorias repetidas.

O correto é mudar a consulta, fazer um select simples na tabela de categoria(`categoria_produto`) e exibir o resultado(id, nome/descrição) no combo.

```
SELECT idCategoria, nomeCategoria FROM categoria_produto
```

No php/html:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["idCategoria"]; ?>">
   <?php echo $row["nomeCategoria"]; ?>
</option>
```

Comment: Atenção que isso retorna inclusive categorias sem produto. Para evitar isso precisaria manter o join e pedir distinct, sem pedir os dados dos produtos

Comment: @bfavaretto e se precisar cadastrar um produto com uma categoria recém criada(zero produtos associados), pelo menos pensei nesse caso p dar a resposta.

Comment: Verdade, depende do uso. No formulário faz mesmo sentido mostrar todas.